# Delete the first char from imploded data using php

Tags: php, string, replace, implode

I have the following code

```
<td class="t-value h6"><?php echo implode('<br> ', $datas);
```

this code dump result like this

```
a.first element<br>
B.seconds element<br>
c.third element <br>
d.etc
```

what I want is to hide the first and second character of each element I tried

```
<td class="t-value h6"><?php  
$datas = implode('<br/>', $datas);
echo substr($datas, 2);
```

but that did work only for the first element and I want it to apply to all elements inside data

thanks verry mx

Comment: You could always output each item 1 at a time using `foreach()` and process them that way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regex to do this work in `preg_replace()` function

```
$newDates = preg_replace("/^\w\./m", "", $dates)
```

Check result in [demo](https://3v4l.org/tDCNu)

Comment: oh ur code worked much better because didnt affect other elements inside $d but i cant understand how ? thats exactly what i wanted but how did u target only the ones with a. b. ...etc ?

Comment: @OmarAguado Regex created for this purpose that select special part of string. In this case regex select any character and dot after it that writed after `<br>`

Answer (score 0):

Work with each array element separately and then do implode.

```
$data2 = array();
foreach($datas as $d){
    $data2[] = substr($d, 2);
}
$data2 = implode('<br/>', $data2);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is probably easier to use preg_replace for this, depending on your willingnes to use regexp.

For example this would solve the issue as long as you do not have the same pattern somewhere else.

```
$output = preg_replace("/\w\./", "", $datas);
```